# How to make number of panels = number of iterations in for loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, iteration, jpanel

How do I make number of panels equal to number of iterations in for loop in Java?

E.g

4 iterations will have 4 panels with *different* name.

Thanks

Comment: Use a for loop and create four different "panels" inside of the loop.  If you still need a more detailed answer, you may wish to ask a more detailed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-_- is **that** what you want?

```
List<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setName("1337 PANEL No.: " +String.valueOf(i));
    panels.add(p);
}
for (JPanel p : panels) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Comment: That's actually what he asked for, but I can't understand why he wants to use the name attribute since it doesn't make any point.

Comment: Maybe wants a TitledBorder, in which case he'd use p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("1337 PANEL No.: " +String.valueOf(i)));

Comment: The original question is one of the worst I've seen today as it gives very little detail as to what he truly wants or why he wants it.

Comment: @ MR Hovercraft Full Of Eels You didnt understand my question????? Let me tell you step by step                                      1) I want to make a for loop .eg a for loop runs 10 times(The no of iterations will be given by user at runtime)
2) In that for loop, i want to make (10 )different panels which have "different" names in that for loop.(for this example 10)
3) The basic idea here is that i want to take input at run time, and in a for loop i want to make no of panels= that input size :-)
Hope this clarifies the question

Comment: @ kaj i want to have panels with different names because i want to put different size
buttons with in different panels

Answer (score 0):

I'll play: are you thinking of [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)?

Comment: No.. Not thinking of JTabbedPane

Comment: @Muhammad - oh, that's good to know. But a better question would have made this answer unnecessary. And if *D1e* gave you the answer you were looking for, you should accept it.

Comment: @Muhammad - actually, you didn't. There's a "check" mark next to the answer. To accept an answer, you have to click it.